# Google contacts API 401 error RestClient::Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to retrieve the Google contacts from a user in Ruby on rails using Restclient, but I every time I tried, I face a Restclient 401 Unauthorized error on my query line. I assume that my query is wrong or missgin something, but I didn't find anything usefull in the Google Contact API doc. 
Any idea ?

Here's my scope

```
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/+https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
```

Here's my method I call with a freshly received access_token

```
def import_google_contact(user_email, access_token)
  r = RestClient.get "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/#{user_email}/full?access_token=#{access_token}"
  ...
end
```

Which is weird since I manage to get the user email just before in the same method using this request

```
r = RestClient.get "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=#{access_token}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I didn't put the right parameter in the scope to request contacts data? I replaced it by

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
```

This is weird because Google accepts a wrong one during the authorization process