# Google Contacts API not returning output

Tags: javascript, ajax, contacts, google-contacts-api

It was working correctly, but yesterday it started giving 401. I have tried with [Google contacts API 401 error RestClient::Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528286/google-contacts-api-401-error-restclientunauthorized)

```
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=ya29.XXXXXXXWLNLPslUUOifL1pu63cGG_DAkEHeh-VjjOGBYzgJAp65-RRrIYmIbGnHiZ5VwC6KpBPYstaSEoBgXOaf0kmuPqIL_-RllkGJKPh1uqTCJoN4k1YZl7Jdp-A&alt=json&max-results=9999',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,        
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#output').html(response.responseText);

        },
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(error.Message);
}
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- I don't think that dataType is correct. JSONP URL must have a
  "callback" parameter to your JS function

  take a look at:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
- Also there is an "access_token" in your URL parameter which sometimes
  can be used only once by some services. It depends on the endpoint
  you are talking to and how they handle their authentication process.